# Exclude all images on CSV import in Magento 1.6.2 by changing Adapter/Product.php

Tags: magento

I am looking to mass import images into magento 1.6.2, but I notice on my initial test that the images which I uploaded were included in the additional views area also. Meaning my image, small image and thumbnail were all linked to the additional views. Would changing the line (792) in

appcode/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php

```
$addedFilesCorrespondence = $mediaGalleryBackendModel->addImagesWithDifferentMediaAttributes(
            $product,
            $arrayToMassAdd, Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import',
            false,
            false
        );


        to:

$addedFilesCorrespondence = $mediaGalleryBackendModel->addImagesWithDifferentMediaAttributes(
            $product,
            $arrayToMassAdd, Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import',
            false,
            true
        );
```

help to avoid in having to go to each product and check exclude from additional views? Or is there another field that is need in the cvs import to avoid this?

Comment: I'm interested in excluding just the thumbnail image myself.  It would be nice if there was a column you could add to the csv file to handle this :/  Seems like a no-brainer

Comment: You're almost done. You just need to add this in your data flow advanced profile xml

    `<var name="exclude_images"><![CDATA[true]]></var>`